# Query ArangoDB for Arrays

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am having a problem querying ArangoDB in java for a value of Arrays. I have tried with both String[] and ArrayList, both with no success.

My query:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER @categoriesArray IN document.categories[*].title RETURN document
```

BindParams:

```
Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("categoriesArray", categoriesArray).get();
```

`categoriesArray` contains a bunch of Strings. I'm not sure why it isn't returning any results, because if I query using:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER "Politics" IN document.categories[*].title RETURN document
```

I get the results I am looking for. Just not when using an Array or ArrayList.

I also tried querying for:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER ["Politics","Law] IN document.categories[*].title RETURN document
```

in order to emulate an ArrayList, but this doesn't return any results. I would query using a bunch of individual Strings, but there are too many and I get an error from the Java driver when querying with a String that long. Thus, I must query using an Array or ArrayList.

An example of the categoriesArray:

```
["Politics", "Law", "Nature"]
```

A sample image of the database:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that the `IN` operator works by searching for the value on its left-hand side in each member of the array on the right side.

With the following the query, this will work if "Politics" is a member of `document.categories[*].title`:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER "Politics" IN document.categories[*].title RETURN document
```

However the following will not work query even if "Politics" is a member of `document.categories[*].title`:

```
FOR document IN documents FILTER [ "Politics", "Law" ] IN document.categories[*].title RETURN document
```

This is because it will be searched for the exact value `[ "Politics", "Law" ]` in each member on the right side, and this will not be present. What you are probably looking for is a comparison that looks for `"Politics"` and `"Law"` separately, e.g.:

```
FOR document IN documents 
LET contained = (
  FOR title IN [ "Politics", "Law" ]   /* or @categoriesArray */
    FILTER title IN document.categories[*].title 
    RETURN title
)
FILTER LENGTH(contained) > 0
RETURN document
```

Comment: How about `LET categories = ["Politics", "Law"]`, `LET cat_length = LENGTH(categories)` & `FILTER cat_length == LENGTH(INTERSECTION(categories, document.categories[*].title))`? Code looks cleaner, but dunno about performance and memory-consumption. Or is it possible to add support for Sets in AQL? Like `FILTER SET(["Politics", "Law"]) IN SET(document.categories[*].title)`. Or in JS, one can do: `let arr = ["Law", "Science", "Politics"]; ["Politics","Law"].every(elem => arr.indexOf(elem) != -1)`. How about `EVERY()` and `SOME()` in AQL? `SOME(["Law","Politics"], doc.categories[*].title))`

Comment: I agree, `EVERY` and `SOME` would be useful in AQL. I am not sure if providing them as functions would provide the most intuitive syntax, but would probably be easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Arango also (now) has [Array Comparison Operators](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operators.html#array-comparison-operators) which allow searching `ALL IN`, `ANY IN`, or `NONE IN`

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ALL IN  [ 2, 3, 4 ]  // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ALL IN  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  NONE IN  [ 3 ]       // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  NONE IN  [ 23, 42 ]  // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY IN  [ 4, 5, 6 ]  // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY IN  [ 1, 42 ]    // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY ==  2            // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY ==  4            // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY >  0             // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ANY <=  1            // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  NONE <  99           // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  NONE >  10           // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ALL >  2             // false
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ALL >  0             // true
[ 1, 2, 3 ]  ALL >=  3            // false
["foo", "bar"]  ALL !=  "moo"     // true
["foo", "bar"]  NONE ==  "bar"    // false
["foo", "bar"]  ANY ==  "foo"     // true
```

So you could now filter by:

```
FOR document IN documents 
    FILTER ["Politics", "Law] ANY IN (document.categories[*].title)[**]
    RETURN document
```